# Javascript simulating keyPress on search input

Tags: javascript, keypress, search-suggestion

suppose I have following string and following element:

```
var s = "aa"
<input id="inet-field" class="suggest-input js-suggest-input" ...">
```

Now what I want to achieve is that I want to dispatch some event which will invoke suggestion[image]

I tried following but without success:

```
 var doc = document.getElementById("inet-field");
 var kEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
 var s = "aa"
 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
     kEvent.initEvent("keypress", true, true);
     kEvent.keyCode = 94;
     doc.dispatchEvent(kEvent);
 }
```

What I am doing wrong ? I am using Chromium browser.

Comment: Paste your code on fiddle

Comment: The suggestion from google and other search engines doesn't come from a key pressed in runtime. What if the user don't want the runtime-pressed key? If I want to type `aab`, with your idea my result will be `aaab`

Comment: Ok, I will try to explain what I am really trying to achieve. What I am actually doing is developing some automation tool. Now suppose that user write text "aa" to this search field and then click on some suggestion. I cannot simply do `searchfield.value = "aa"`, because this will not invoke this sugestion and next step will fail. So I need to somehow handle this, like really simulate keypressing on that element. @CliffBurton

Comment: try to look some `autocomplete` js code

Answer (score 0):

Should using an external library be an option, I would like to suggest [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

It's easy to use and fast.